# Find the first value of $n$ such that $11^n$ contains $n+2$ digits, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A friend has given me a math problem to solve,the problem is as follows:

> Find the fist value of $n$ ,for which:
>    $(11)^n$ contains $(n+2)$ digits, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I have done trial and error method using calculator to find its answer,
and found answer is:
$$n=25$$
But how to solve this problem analytically?Any help...

For convenience of understanding this problem; consider this example:
$$11^3 =1331\to 4 \text{ digits} \implies (n+1) \text{ digits for n}=3$$

Comment: Have you ever heard of logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have $n+2$ digits the number must be greater than $10^{n+1}$ (and less than $10^{n+2}$, but we don't care about that).  So we need 
$$11^n \gt 10^{n+1}\\n \log(11) \gt (n+1) \log (10)\\1-\frac 1{n+1} \gt \frac {\log (10)}{\log (11)}$$

Comment: Probably easier to do it as $$\frac{\log 11}{\log 10}>1+\frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$10^k$ has $k+1 $ digits.

$10^{k+1}$ has $k +2$ digits.

And $10^{k+1} - 1$ has $k+1$ digits.

so if $M$ has $n+2$ digits then $10^{n+1} \le M < 10^{n+2}$ and $n+1 \le \log M < n+2$.

So to solve $11^n$ having $n+2$ digits we need

$n+1 \le \log 11^n < n+2$.

So we need $n+1 \le \log 11^n = n \log 11$ or $\frac {n+1}{n} = 1+\frac 1n \le \log 11$ or $\frac 1n \le \log 11 - 1$ or $n \ge \frac 1{\log 11 - 1}$.

So we need the smallest possible integer $n \ge \frac 1{\log 11-1}\approx \frac 1{1.041392685158225040750199971243-1} \approx \frac 1{.041392685158225040750199971243}\approx 24.16$.

So $n =25$.

$11^{25}$ has $27$ digits.